# Object files without ELF header or ways to reduce object file size with GCC?

Tags: gcc

I'm using GCC to compile some C code. Is there a way to strip e.g. the ELF header from object file and make linker to add the header? Or, are there other possibilities to strip down the resulting object file size than the obvious -Os and -s flags?(-ffast-math, -fomit-frame-pointer, -fshort-doubles do help to reduce the code size but hexdumping the object file reveals huge amounts of zeroes which are "seemingly" useless).

Tools like strip/sstrip aren't really of much use as the object file has to preserve the symbols(it will be linked later on). (-strip-unneeded and -R .comment -R .gnu.version do their magic though).

What I'm doing is something which requires me to bundle (compressed) object file to the user and have a script embedded to link it at users-end. Every byte counts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ELF header can't be removed and restored later on, as valuable information is stored there and then lost forever (like file offsets for some tables, architecture, etc. IIRC). You've already listed almost everything that you can do to reduce the size, except maybe bzip'ing.

Comment: Oh, okay. I believe I need to write a tool which tries to minimize the (compressed) ELF header size. Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the object files through a compression algorith, those "huge amounts of zeroes" should shrink by a large factor, since they have low information content. You might want to investigate a better compression algorithnm, perhaps it's possible to gain more there than by going to a modified/non-standard "hacked" object file format, if even possible.

Comment: I'm using 7z to compress the object files. It does marvelous job indeed, but I'd imagine that getting rid of even some random bytes here and there could make big differences. Right now the object file compresses down to 540 bytes with the embedded decompression+linking script. My goal would be to go down to <= 512 bytes. I'm fairly certain(Hehe) that the code is around as optimal as it gets with C, as it's less than 35 lines and I've tried just about every trick in the book to go smaller, and I'm hitting the wall. Next step is to investigate the ELF header and zero out any unneeded bytes.

Comment: @youngdood: A nice read that might interest you: [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html). He creates the smallest possible ELF program and explains everything about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing with `-fdata-sections`, `-ffunction-sections` and `-Wl,--gc-sections`, but this is not safe, so be sure to understand how they work before using them.